# Should I close my French PEL to invest in ETFs?

Tags: etf, savings-account, housing, france

My grandmother opened for me a PEL. I am going to give a complete description of what is a PEL as it is most probably unknown for money.SE. I am French and the PEL is a saving account that means: "Plan Epargne Logement" ("House Savings Plan"). Its aim is to save for the next time you will have to finance either:

- The buying of your primary house
- The construction of your primary house
- The buying of terrain for your primary house
- Restoration works in your house

She opened it in 2014 just when I had 18 and the age to open one.

Citing [France government website](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16140), you can have it [all in English here](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16140?lang=en):

- PEL opened after 1st August 2016 returns a guarantee 1% per year
- **Interest** My PEL, opened before this date, returns a guarantee 2% per year
- **Taxes** all above interests are taxed at 30% by the French government. I have earn 655€44 interests since the PEL is opened, after tax deductions
- **PEL Credit** A PEL gives you the opportunity to contract a credit. In my case, I can contract a credit for a house of a maximal value of 92,000€ with a 2.2% interest.
- **Financial Bonus** In the case your PEL makes you contract the aforementioned loan, a financial bonus of maximum value of 1,000€ corresponding to, in my case, 50% of all interests gain during the PEL length. In my case (November 2021) this Financial Bonus is worth 371€11. The maximum value of 1,000€ can be enlarged to 1,500€ if the accommodation you buy meets energetic saving requirements set by France.
- **PEL Length** A PEL can receive payments during at most 10 years. Meaning, in my case, I won't be able to make payments starting at 2024. Interests will be paid during 5 years after the previous 10 years meaning a PEL pays interests during 15 years. PEL Credit and Financial Bonus still work after 15 years.
- **Periodic payments** It is mandatory to have periodic payments of at least 45€ per month into your PEL. You can have as many punctual payments as you want.
- **Total amount** There is currently 13,950€ in this PEL.

About my financial situation, I am a PhD student in computer science and don't earn a lot each month. I hope I will manage to have a permanent position at the end of my thesis, in two years. I don't need those 14,000€ yet and my goal is still, as in 2014, to save until I get a house credit. I discovered in 2019 during Covid-19 that ETF are more efficient than my PEL (and also more risky). From this point I stopped all payments to my PEL except the 50€ I send monthly that are mandatory.

I am currently thinking of closing the PEL and put the 14000€ in ETF, S&P500, Nasdaq 100, Euro Stoxx 50, China and so on, as I am used to since one year and half. I managed to put 11 000€ in ETF and actions (90% ETF, 10% actions) since 2020. It would have gone to my PEL if I would not have discovered the Stocks. My thoughts now are, is it worth closing my PEL?

It is not an obvious question because the 2% interests are guaranteed each year. It could be interesting to get the 92 000€ credit and would be a loss to not get the financial bonus. But I saw S&P500, dividends reinvested gains an average 6% per year since more than 20 years... I am still young, 24 years old, and that is a big decision for me. Noone in my family or friends can help, that is why I am questioning here :D

Comment: Is it the case that there are tax benefits with the interest gained on the PEL which you will lose if you close it and concentrate all your funds in ETFS?

Comment: @24601, I think there are no tax benefits with the interests gained on the PEL. You are paid 2% interests per year and the French state taxes 30% of those 2%. However if you close your PEL without contracting a loan, you are not eligible to the Financial Bonus and the PEL Credit mentioned in the post

Comment: I see. [This Service-Public reference](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16140?lang=en) explains the tax implication. **Withdrawal after 4 years does not result in penalties**

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I did not know it exists in English, I am adding to my post

Comment: easy to change the language from French to English above the Share options - I use it all the time (Anglais résident en France)